# Could ">" be included in a bash Variable?

Tags: bash, quoting, variable

**Current approach**:

```
sudo awk 'BEGIN{printf "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n<hello>\n\t<world>\n";} {print "\t\t",$0}END{printf "\t </world>\n</hello>\n"}' hello > hello2
```

**Preferred approach does not work**:

`hello > hello2` would like to be defined as a variable to avoid code duplication

```
$CURRENT_TO_OUT=hello > hello2

echo "CP1" $CURRENT_TO_OUT

sudo awk 'BEGIN{printf "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n<hello>\n\t<world>\n";} {print "\t\t",$0}END{printf "\t </world>\n</hello>\n"}' $CURRENT_TO_OUT
```

**Output $CURRENT_TO_OUT:**

`CP1 hello`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After variable expansion, the command line is normally not re-interpreted. 
You would need calls to `eval` for the wanted behaviour.

You have actually a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).
To avoid code duplications, use a shell function instead:

```
convert_func(){
   echo "CP1 $1" > "$2"
   sudo awk 'BEGIN{printf "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n<hello>\n\t<world>\n";} {print "\t\t",$0}END{printf "\t </world>\n</hello>\n"}' "$1" > "$2"
}

convert_func input1 targetfile1
convert_func input2 targetfile2
```